# Apache Maven generate fails to create project using the command provided at the official site

Tags: java, macos-mojave, maven

OS: MacOS Mojave (Version: 10.14.3)
Software in question: Apache Maven
Objective: Create a new Maven project (in an empty directory)
Method: Execute command in Terminal

Reference: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

I am following instructions in the above link and trying to create a project using the command as mentioned there. The command is:

*mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false*

I have verified that Java and Maven are properly installed and verified the output of mvn -v command, which indicates its correctly installed.

However, the next step fails due to the following error:
**org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException:** Could not find goal *'generate-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app-DartifactId=my-app-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart-DarchetypeVersion=1.4-DinteractiveMode=false' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog*

The printed results also refers this URL for help:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
But I don't understand Maven and its online repositories that much yet.

How can I find out why the command failed with this Error? I tried searching online for answers and on Stackoverflow, but there aren't any related to this error and this context (goal: generate).

Can anyone guide me towards any direction? I ran the command by enabling maven full error stack trace and debug and saved it. I can add it if it will be of any help (let me know)

Comment: Not sure, but you seem to be missing a whitespace after "generate". At least in the error message.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Hey, yes that is the problem! So I feel its best to copy paste the command into the terminal directly to avoid any mistypes or left out character (in this case the missing whitespace character!)
Thank you very much for helping out with this!

Comment: You're very welcome! Always glad to help. I posted an answer to help everyone with similar problems to find this more easily. You may accept it as a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException: Could not find goal 'generate-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app-DartifactId=my-app-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart-DarchetypeVersion=1.4-DinteractiveMode=false' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog

There's a whitespace missing after `generate` and before `-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app...`. All the `-D` parameters also require a whitespace before them. Otherwise the command looks fine.

> So I feel its best to copy paste the command into the terminal directly to avoid any mistypes or left out character (in this case the missing whitespace character!)

Yes, the best way to prevent this is to paste the command or just use an IDE that can run the goal for you.